# MySQL Stored Procedure select statement finding inaccurate result

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that's supposed to simply check if an email already exists and return a boolean TRUE or FALSE based on if an ID is found

The table looks like this:
[image]

The result is this:

[image]

Which is wildly incorrect

Here's the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `EmailExists` (email VARCHAR(255), OUT output BOOL)
email_exists_proc:BEGIN
    DECLARE existing_id CHAR(36);
    DECLARE existing_email2 varchar(255);
    DECLARE found_name varchar(255);

    SELECT 
        `id`, `email`, `display_name` INTO existing_id, existing_email2, found_name
    FROM `account`
    WHERE `email` = email
    LIMIT 1;

    SELECT "EMail Exists", existing_email2, " == ", email, " ? ", existing_id, "name: ", found_name, existing_id IS NOT NULL;

    SELECT existing_id IS NOT NULL INTO output;
END$$
```

It's pretty basic query, here's the call:

```
CALL EmailExists("something@something.com", @exists);
SELECT @exists; # this returns 1 right now, it should be 0, but it's "finding" the provided email, somehow.
```

What I missing, what am I doing wrong here? Why does `existing_email2` end up mirroring `email`? The value doesn't exist in the table.

Comment: Limit without order by is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualify the references to columns in the queries, so identifiers meant to reference a column are actually referencing a column, rather than a procedure variable.

The backticks are used to escape identifiers. The backticks do not identify which identifiers reference columns and which reference procedure variables.

Assigning table alias `a` to the account table, and qualifying all column references with `a.`

```
  SELECT a.`id`
       , a.`email`
       , a.`display_name`
    FROM `account` a
   WHERE a.`email` = email
   LIMIT 1
    INTO existing_id
       , existing_email2
       , found_name
  ;
```

---

Best practice is to use names for procedure variables that *differ* from column names.

My personal preference would be to use a different name for the procedure value

```
... PROCEDURE `EmailExists` (as_email VARCHAR(255), ...
                             ^^
```

And then this

```
   WHERE a.`email` = as_email
```

is less ambiguous to the human reader.

Then, to get the behavior in the original code, we would have written:

```
   WHERE as_email = as_email
```

which makes it a little more obvious why every row in `accounts` satisfies that condition for any non-NULL value provided for `as_email`.

---

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

> **Name Conflicts within Stored Routines**
>
> The same identifier might be used for a routine parameter, a local variable, and a table column. Also, the same local variable name can be used in nested blocks. For example:
>
> In such cases, the identifier is ambiguous and the following precedence rules apply:
>
> - A local variable takes precedence over a routine parameter or table column.
> - A routine parameter **takes precedence** over a table column.

Comment: You were totally right. I had it in my head that the scoping would prevent such a think automatically. But applying an alias totally worked. Thank you!